# GitHub API Create Repo returning 403?

Tags: github, request, github-api, github-api-v3, github-app

I'm making a GitHub app, and I'm trying to create a repo according to this documentation

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user

When I make a GET request to that URL, it works and I get the user's repos, but making a post request like this:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.github.com/user/repos \
  --header 'authorization: token  [user_access_token]' \
  --data '{"name": "test"}'
```

Returns this

```
{
  "message": "Resource not accessible by integration",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

My app has access to this permission:
[image: My app has access to this permission:]